# Rails routes with / at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to change the routes for one resource (at least only show, index) to have / at the end?

For example:

```
test.heroku.com/books/1/ #the last / will produce an error
```

Using `Rails 3.0.9`. Server `heroku.com`

routes.rb:

```
resources :books
```

Error:

```
2011-08-06T21:41:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/books/1/?ref=bookmarks" for        213.229.110.100 at 2011-08-06 14:41:35 -0700
2011-08-06T21:41:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T21:41:35+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/books/1"):
```

But when I point my browser to

```
http://test.heroku.com/books/1
```

is working

```
http://test.heroku.com/books/1/
```

is working too.

But if I use:

```
http://test.heroku.com/books/1/
```

as a canvas url for a Facebook Application is not working.

Thanks

EDIT Complete ERROR LOG:

```
2011-08-06T22:07:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/books/1/?ref=bookmarks" for  213.229.110.100 at 2011-08-06 15:08:13 -0700
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/books/1"):
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 heroku[router]: POST test.heroku.com/books/1/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=136ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-08-06T22:08:13+00:00 heroku[nginx]: POST /books/1/?ref=bookmarks HTTP/1.1 | 213.229.110.100 | 904 | http | 404
```

Comment: provide your routes.rb file, the bug might be elsewhere

Comment: Please take a look to the new logs. I think I have a problem because facebook is doing `POST` instead of `GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wont produce an error if you are making use of the built-in resourceful routing:

```
resources :books
```

If you have defined a custom route (perhaps in the process of upgrading a 2.3 app to Rails 3) without accounting for a trailing slash, then you might not be so lucky. If this is the case and you're not sure how to adjust, you should edit your question and add the relevant part of your routing file (config/routes.rb).

---

#### Update

<del>Okay so after looking at the log output you posted I see what's happening. Facebook is requesting `/books/1/?ref=bookmarks`. This is NOT the same as `/books/1/`, which Rails interprets as actually being a request to the `/books/1` resource. Why bother with the trailing slash in this case? It's inaccurate canonically speaking, and clearly it's causing problems.</del>

#### Update 2

You can add `POST /books/1` as a route to the resourceful routes like so:

```
resources :books do 
  post '/' => :show, :on => :member
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question. I first thought that it was an error with my route file. But its working really good if I point the browser to the URL. But it's not working if I set it as a Canvas URL ..

Comment: Mate I tried to point the browser to `http://test.heroku.com/books/1/?ref=bookmarks` and its working just fine. I think the problem is with the `POST` request. `show` method require a get request right?

Comment: Can I change something in show method to accept post request as well or its better to create a new method?

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't see that. Yeah, using POST to GET a resource isn't RESTful, so you'll have to add that route manually. Updating again right now.

Comment: Don't I have to tell something about the `1` (:id). if I put / will it get the id as well ? In addition what does `:on => member` do? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't know what or how is getting `/` to `:id/` and what `:on => member` means but its working:) Thanks mate:)

Comment: The `:on` option defines whether this custom route is on the collection (i.e. `/books/your-route`) or a member of the collection (i.e. `/books/1/your-route`). Cheers!